# Props is not getting passes with Jump action in react native router flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am having two type of navigation based on condition but when I use Actions.push with currentPurse to pass it is working fine, but when navigate using Actions.jump then currentPurse is undefined.

```html
if(env.config.tabAvailable){
    Actions.jump('PurseTransaction', { currentPurse: purse})
} else {
    Actions.push('PurseTransaction', { currentPurse: purse})
}
```

If any one have solution to pass props with jump action then it would be helpful.